# Script display from an external file in Jupyter Notebook with syntax-highlighting

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, syntax-highlighting

I am making a tutorial using Jupyter and I would like to display the content of an external Python script. Printing the content of the file is trivial, but I am interested in a color-coded/syntax-highlighted text (either in a markdown cell or as an output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ipython's Markdown module:

````
from IPython.display import Markdown as md

script = """
x = 2
if x*2 > 2:
    print('x > 2')
else:
    x = None
"""

md("```Python" + script + "```")
````

Will output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use the [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html): %load

```
%load testLoad.py
```

***This is assuming the external file is in your Jupyter Notebook starting directory***

If you only want specific lines (say between lines 5 and 10 and also line 15) of your python code to be displayed then:

```
%load -r 5-10,15 testLoad.py
```

You can find out the options of a magic command by adding a '?' at the end of the magic command:

```
%load?
```

*Magic commands are shortcuts that are used to help do things much faster in Jupyter Notebook. They are great for beginners as they generally contain everything a beginner needs to display and test Jupyter Notebook*

Here is a link to all magic commands in IPython for Jupyter Notebook:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Comment: This loads the code of the file into the notebook, ready to be executed. It is not simply printing the contents of the file, and if the file is changed the notebook will not be updated if re-run.

Answer (score 1):

The following [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) (starting with `%`) can be used to output the contents of a python script with highlighting.

```py
%pycat script.py
```

Alternatively, it is possible to run shell commands by prepending them with `!`. If you have pygmentize installed, it is possible to use that (though I recommend `%pycat` for notebooks):

```py
!pygmentize -g script.py
```

You can also use the old but good UNIX tool `cat` on all POSIX compliant systems (Unix, Mac, Linux, BSD). Then you won't get highlighting, but it might be more suitable for text files:

```py
!cat data.txt
```

On POSIX compliant systems notebooks also come with an alias to `cat` in the form of a magic command:

```py
%cat data.txt
```